# How to add dynamic date footer to project print-out?

Tags: ms-project-2013

I see other people printing our project's Gantt chart with an up-to-the-date date on the bottom.

How do they to do that? Is it automatic or must one do something every time one prints the chart?

Comment: @tiagoperes Please stop suggesting for the ms-project tag to be added. Please read the description of the tag - it should not be combined with the ms-project-2013 tag.

Comment: @Sarov In this specific case the solution is not version specific.

Comment: @tiagoperes If that's true then the version-specific tag should be *replaced* by the version-agnostic one; the Question should not contain both.

Comment: @Sarov that's your opinion. Already had that discussion with moderators from this community and we agreed it's acceptable with both. Not for this particular case but generally speaking.

Comment: @tiagoperes Can you provide a link?

Comment: Can't find the link. But people involved were @Todd A. Jacobs , Tiago Cardoso , Goncalo Peres and one or two more other members. The context had to do specifically with having a lot of old questions in the initial thread because of ms-project / ms-project-x tags.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88026/discussion-between-sarov-and-tiagoperes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/add-a-header-footer-or-legend-when-printing-c2164fee-9d34-4dbf-8b14-61b5d2825873):

> In the **File** tab, click **Print**, then click **Page Setup**.
>
> On the *Header, Footer, or Legend* tab, click the Left, Center, or Right tab.

Now choose the date icon and the field will auto-fill and update when you print.